# form.serialize() for input fields and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, textarea

I have a multi step form with different input fields and one textarea. I'd like to serialize these using form.serialize(). But unfortunately, I can't serialize input fields and textareas at the same time. Here is the code for better understanding. I need to serialize it **step by step**.

```js
form = $('form .part-2 input'); // textarea is missing
formData = form.serialize();
$('#output').text(formData);

// form = $('form .part-2'); // input field(s) and textarea are missing
// formData = form.serialize();
// $('#output').text(formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.html" method="post">
  <div class="part-1">
    <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Name1">
    <input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Name1">
  </div>
  <div class="part-2">
    <input type="text" name="name3" placeholder="Name1">
    <div class="textarea">
      <textarea name="name4" maxlength="50"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<span id="output"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:input` instead which can target both:

```js
form = $('form .part-2 :input'); // textarea is missing
 //--------------------^^^^^^-------this is required
formData = form.serialize();
$('#output').text(formData);

// form = $('form .part-2'); // input field(s) and textarea are missing
// formData = form.serialize();
// $('#output').text(formData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="index.html" method="post">
  <div class="part-1">
    <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Name1">
    <input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Name1">
  </div>
  <div class="part-2">
    <input type="text" name="name3" placeholder="Name1">
    <div class="textarea">
      <textarea name="name4" maxlength="50"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted. But I have to wait 5 more minutes. You were to fast :).